# Cannot slide sliding_up_panel plugin when panel is Listview in flutter

Tags: flutter, slide

Added [this](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel) plugin to flutter project. Here is my following code

```
body: SlidingUpPanel(
        backdropEnabled:true,
        panelSnapping:true,
        defaultPanelState:PanelState.CLOSED,
        panel:ListView.separated(
          itemCount:2,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){           
         return Text('ass');
         },
         separatorBuilder:(BuildContext context, int index){return Divider();},
         collapsed:Container(),
        ),
```

The problem is when I fully open the slider , I cannot slide it back. If remove Listview it works fine. So how can I slide it back with listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in v1.0.0 of sliding_up_panel. If you update your pubspec.yaml to include v1.0.0 of sliding_up_panel and follow [this](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel#using-the-panelcontroller) guide, you should be able to get the desired behavior.

Here's what it would look like for your layout:

```dart
body: SlidingUpPanel(
  backdropEnabled: true,
  panelSnapping: true,
  defaultPanelState: PanelState.CLOSED,
  panelBuilder: (ScrollController sc) => ListView.separated(
    controller: sc,
    itemCount: 2,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){           
      return Text('ass');
    },
    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
      return Divider();
    },
  ),
  collapsed: Container(),
)
```